# Sample code for accessing external RAM using FX2 Microcontroller

Tags: 8051

I have a problem about accessing external RAM's using Cypress FX2 Microcontrollers. Can anyone tell me about what register should I use. Just like 8051 MCU's it has A15-A0 pins for address buses and D7-D0 pins for data buses Chip select, Output enable and Write enable strobes. 
The MCU is CY7C68013A FX2. I can't seem to find what register must be used to generate a signal for accesing the external RAM. The register for using this functions should be the same with 8051. In the microcontroller it has a dedicated pin i.e. A15(Address bus MSB) , D7(Data bus MSB)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the external RAM - short `XRAM` - using the 16-Bit `DPTR` register:

```
; write   register A value to XRAM address  indicated by DPTR
MOVX  @DPTR,A

; read XRAM to register A
MOVX  A,@DPTR
```

Comment: 8051 Memory configuration explained [at esacademy](http://www.esacademy.com/en/library/technical-articles-and-documents/8051-programming/8051-memory-configurations-with-c-compilers.html).